# How to save one_hot from tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0, one-hot-encoding

I am doing a Natural Language Processing Project.

for this I am using one hot encoding from tensorflow.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
```

I have generated a sequence of numbers for a particular sentence .
i.e.[7473,
7491,
6019,
5950,
7562,
1396,
4641,
7098,
135,
6836,
4566,
934,
5085,
5521,
5786,
2854]

Now. I have created a lstm model and want to deploy using Flask API.
But , now , the one hot is not generating the same sequence of numbers for the same sentences.

I have tried saving one hot using pickle file ..But it didnt worked.

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(one_hot,"encoder.pkl")
```

I even tried using PythonHashSeed in terminal. They works on the same environment for the same time only.

```
!PYTHONHASHSEED=0
```

But None of them works for another place/future use.

Is there any method to save the one hot encoding list using a dict, json, or any other methods?

Comment: So your question is how to save a list of numbers to a file? There are plenty of answers out there. Or are you asking how to make the encoding reproducible?

Comment: i want to save the encoding dictionary .. like now encoder converts the " earth " into 100 now... i want to save and reuse it again so if anywhere and anytime i use that encoder to encode " earth " , it should give 100..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `pickle` like this but note that `one_hot` only takes one string text input at a time. So you might want to use a different approach as mentioned below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle

one_hot_encoded = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot('This is another fish', n=7)
print(one_hot_encoded)

with open('one_hot.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(one_hot_encoded, f)

with open('one_hot.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    new_one_hot_encoded = pickle.load(f)
    
print(new_one_hot_encoded)
```

```
[1, 6, 4, 3]
[1, 6, 4, 3]
```

You could also use `TextVectorization` and save a word-to-index dictionary with `pickle`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle

data = [
    "You are a fish",
    "This is a fish",
    "He is a fish",
]
layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization()
layer.adapt(data)
vectorized_text = layer(data)
word_index = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(layer.get_vocabulary())}
print(word_index['fish'])

with open('one_hot.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(word_index, f)

with open('one_hot.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    word_index = pickle.load(f)
    
print(word_index['fish'])

2
2
```

Or with `StringLookup`:

```py
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup()
layer.adapt(tf.strings.split(tf.strings.lower(data)))
layer.get_vocabulary()
```

The rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: I want to save the encoding machine/object..not sequence of numbers....  like if my encoder now gives 100 for " earth " .... i want to save and resuse it at another place .... and if i convert the "earth " it should give me 100

Comment: Updated answer.